# Call to fopen() in a DLL from a UWP app returns a NULL pointer. GetLastError() returned ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, uwp, windows-10, c++-cx

I am working on a UWP application that calls a function from a DLL. It supplies the function with the application installation path so that I can go ahead and write some data to it.

I imported the DLL using [LoadPackagedLibrary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-loadpackagedlibrary) as described in [How to: Use Existing C++ Code in a Universal Windows Platform App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/how-to-use-existing-cpp-code-in-a-universal-windows-platform-app?view=vs-2019).

I retrieved the path using `Windows::Storage::StorageFolder^ installedLocation = Windows::ApplicationModel::Package::Current->InstalledLocation;`.

However, when I try to open the file and get a handle to it using `fopen`, I get a NULL pointer. I retrieved the error code using `GetLastError()` and it returned `ERROR_ACCESS_DENINED` error.

What could be the reason for this? Am I missing something? Do I need to declare additional capabilities to ensure that the DLL can access files in the application's installation path?

Answer (score 1):

Writing to the UWP app's installation folder is restricted by design. This is to ensure the integrity of the app installation and to enable seamless, incremental automatic updates for the application package.

If you want to write data you will need to write it to the app's appdata location, not the install location.

Comment: I read the MSFT documentation about file access permissions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions). I understand that there are two default file permissions that need no additional declarations. The ```AppData``` folder and the ```Downloads``` folder. It was also mentioned that the app has access to the files or folders that it creates.

So, I created a file (in the Downloads folder, for example) from within the UWP app and gave its path to the function in the DLL. However, I still see the same error.

Comment: Since I could not ```fopen``` a file that I supplied to the function within the DLL, I tried to check if it works from within the UWP application. 

I created a file in the Downloads folder using ```CreateFileAsync``` and supplied the file's path to the ```fopen``` function but it still returned a ```NULL```.

I also tried doing the same thing in the AppData folder. This time ```fopen``` gives me a handle to the file. 

Why is it not working when a function within the DLL tries to do the same thing?

Comment: When the function within the DLL to access the local folder, can you get a handle from fopen? Will the same issue occur?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT Whenever I try to ```fopen()``` from the function within the DLL, it fails to get a handle irrespective of what path I give it.

Comment: When I pass the AppData directories to fopen() from the function within the DLL, it can return the handle. Can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced?

Answer (score 0):

`fopen()` relies on `CreateFile` to do the actual work. `CreateFile` only knows how to handle filesystem ACLs, not capability-based UWP permissions, and so it always fails with `ACCESS_DENIED` for anything other than your AppData directories (for read/write access) or your install location (for read-only access).

There is a [work-around using `CreateFileFromApp`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59135054/4184842) but it won't work for `fopen()` unless you're willing to statically-link the CRT, which has its cons. For example, you don't get the benefit of automatic security patches and you might not be able to distribute through the Microsoft Store.