# how to use ImportRedirection to hook function? the new feature redirection in windows

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, hook

I found a new feature in windows, API Redirection, this feature allows an application to "redirect" the API imports from its DLLs and to call different APIs instead. Then I read related documentation [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59135054/how-can-i-access-files-like-a-sqlite-database-outside-of-my-apps-folder-in-a) and [Link2](https://www.tiraniddo.dev/2020/02/dll-import-redirection-in-windows-10_8.html) carefully. I create a procedure link A.DLL. I define `Sum()` in A,DLL. I also define `mySum()`in Redirection.DLL. when I start this procedure, I want this procedure imports `A.dll!Sum()` redirect it to `Redirection.dll!mySum()`

in summary, the step maybe:

1. write Redirection.DLL
2. Create a new process with Redirection.DLL

And follow above wiki, defined my own Redirection.DLL as follow:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

int mySum(int a, int b) {
     printf("rewrite! \n");
    return 222222222;
} 

const REDIRECTION_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTOR RedirectionFunction[] = {
   { "Dll1.lib", "Sum", &mySum }
};

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) const REDIRECTION_DESCRIPTOR __RedirectionInformation__ = {
  CURRENT_IMPORT_REDIRECTION_VERSION,
  _countof(RedirectionFunction),
  RedirectionFunction
};
```

A.DLL

```
#include "pch.h"
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) int Sum(int a, int b) {
    printf("orginal dll1. \n");
    return a + b; 
}
```

the procedure(target.exe):

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib,"A.lib") 
#define DLLIMPORT extern "C" _declspec(dllimport)


DLLIMPORT int Sum(int a, int b);

int main() {

    //Sum(1, 2);
    std::cout << "this is injectFuction main process: Hello World!\n";
    std::cout << Sum(1, 2) << std::endl;
    Sleep(10000000);

    return 0; 
}
```

Start procedure with Redirection.DLL by `NtCreateUserProcess`. I guess `NtDLLpath` means start with `NtDLLpath`. But I only start target.exe not with Redirection.DLL and not happen redirection. may I miss some step?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "ntdll.h"
//#pragma comment(lib, "ntdll")


int main()
{
    // Path to the image file from which the process will be created
    UNICODE_STRING NtImagePath;
    UNICODE_STRING NtDLLPath;


    RtlInitUnicodeString(&NtImagePath, (PWSTR)L"\\??\\D:\\newJunFiles\\RedirectionExample\\x64\\Debug\\target.exe");
    RtlInitUnicodeString(&NtDLLPath, (PWSTR)L"\\??\\D:\\newJunFiles\\RedirectionExample\\x64\\Debug\\Redirection.dll");

    // Create the process parameters
    PRTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS ProcessParameters = NULL;
     RtlCreateProcessParametersEx(&ProcessParameters,
        &NtImagePath, &NtDLLPath, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS_NORMALIZED);
    //RtlCreateProcessParametersEx(&ProcessParameters, &NtImagePath, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS_NORMALIZED);

    // Initialize the PS_CREATE_INFO structure
    PS_CREATE_INFO CreateInfo = { 0 };
    CreateInfo.Size = sizeof(CreateInfo);
    CreateInfo.State = PsCreateInitialState;

    // Initialize the PS_ATTRIBUTE_LIST structure
    PPS_ATTRIBUTE_LIST AttributeList = (PS_ATTRIBUTE_LIST*)RtlAllocateHeap(RtlProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sizeof(PS_ATTRIBUTE));
    AttributeList->TotalLength = sizeof(PS_ATTRIBUTE_LIST) - sizeof(PS_ATTRIBUTE);
    AttributeList->Attributes[0].Attribute = PS_ATTRIBUTE_IMAGE_NAME;
    AttributeList->Attributes[0].Size = NtImagePath.Length;
    AttributeList->Attributes[0].Value = (ULONG_PTR)NtImagePath.Buffer;

    // Create the process
    HANDLE hProcess, hThread = NULL;
    NtCreateUserProcess(&hProcess,
        &hThread, 
        PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,
        THREAD_ALL_ACCESS,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
        ProcessParameters,
        &CreateInfo,
        AttributeList);

    // Clean up
    RtlFreeHeap(RtlProcessHeap(), 0, AttributeList);
    RtlDestroyProcessParameters(ProcessParameters);
}
```

Comment: The link you provided requires a login. Do you not have *public* documentation for this "new" redirection API?

Comment: https://www.tiraniddo.dev/2020/02/dll-import-redirection-in-windows-10_8.html

Comment: maybe, it is not new... this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59135054/how-can-i-access-files-like-a-sqlite-database-outside-of-my-apps-folder-in-a) is related to redirection API

Comment: This is not a public API, hence there is no documentation. The linked Stack Overflow Q&A explains that you need a packaged application, plus a packaged application manifest with a `uap7:ImportRedirectionTable` entry. You don't seem to be providing either.

Answer (score 0):

Your redirection table is wrong:

```
const REDIRECTION_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTOR RedirectionFunction[] = {
   { "Dll1.lib", "Sum", &mySum }
```

Should be this:

```
const REDIRECTION_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTOR RedirectionFunction[] = {
   { "A.dll", "Sum", &mySum }
```

The `.lib` file tells the compiler where to find the DLL, and it puts the DLL name into the EXE. At runtime there is no `.lib` file.

Also, please note that `RtlCreateProcessParametersEx` is not a public, supported API. Is there a reason you're not using plain old `CreateProcess`?

Comment: Thanks for point my error `A.dll`. it's my mistake. But it also does not work after I fix this wrong. In my opinion, to make "redirection" work, we should start the process and `redirection.dll` at the same time. but the `createProcess` only starts a process, not with `redirection.dll`.